# Accessing elements of structure inside a map datastructure

Tags: c++, data-structures

I have this structure, and  map datastructure like :

```
#include <map>

struct category {
        int id;
        std::string name;
};

std::map<int, category> categories;
```

Now, using categories I want to display element "name" which is in structure category. But I am not able to access it. Can anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you mean you can't access it?

```
categories[0].name;
```

should be enough.

Comment: Unless `categories` is `const`

Comment: categories[0].name would represent the name for the first element ,right?

Comment: @GWW categories is declared as `std::map<int, category> categories;`

Comment: @UnderDog no, the element with key `0`.

Comment: @luchian : Pardon me for my ignorance, I didnt understand it well. structure category is key for my map function. There are 10 elements in my map function and each one has a name. Now I want to access member "name" of structure for each element, so by using categories[0].name, I would be able to do that?

Comment: @UnderDog no, the category is the value of the map. `int` is the key. You probably want `std::map<std::string, category>` if you want to access an object through a string.